# Turbolinks or some other rails js file that I might be missing?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have ran into this issue where:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for @blog, :url => user_blogs_path(current_user.id), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <h1>Create Your Blog</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
        <%= render :partial => 'form_errors', :object => @blog %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= render :partial => 'blog_form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <hr>
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <%= f.submit "Create", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Clicking submit in the form above does nothing. I have to refresh the page, fill out the form and then and only then does clicking create work.

The Controller file:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :redirect_not_blog_owner, except: [:index, :new, :create, :show]

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  def index
    @blogs = User.find_by!(id: params[:user_id]).blogs.all()
  end

  def show
    @blog = Blog.find_by!(id: params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_create_params)
    @blog.user_name = current_user.user_name

    if @blog.save && current_user.add_role_for_blog(@blog, Role.find_by(role: 'Blog-Owner'))
      flash[:success] = 'New Blog Created!'
      redirect_to user_blogs_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @blog = Blog.find_by!(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @blog = Blog.find_by!(id: params[:id])
    user = User.find_by!(id: params[:user_id])

    @blog.update_attributes(blog_update_params)
    if @blog.save
      flash[:success] = 'Updated Blog'
      redirect_to user_blog_path(user.id, @blog.id)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    blog = Blog.find_by!(id: params[:id])
    user = User.find_by!(id: params[:user_id])

    if user && blog
      user.delete_role_for_blog(blog)
      blog.destroy!
      redirect_to user_blogs_path
      flash[:success] = 'Deleted Blog!'
    end
  end

  def blog_create_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :blog_description)
  end

  def blog_update_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :blog_description)
  end

end
```

Thats the controller, The new and the create action all work properly. That is when the form actually submits. So I thought I was missing a rails gem so heres my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.7.2"
gem 'kaminari'

gem 'rspec-rails', '2.99.0', group: [:test, :development]
gem 'letter_opener', group: [:development]

gem 'promiscuous', :git => 'git@github.com:promiscuous-io/promiscuous.git'
gem "active_model_serializers", '0.8.1'
gem 'ancestry', '2.1.0'
gem 'rack-attack'
gem 'backbone-on-rails'
gem 'react-rails',  :git => 'git@github.com:reactjs/react-rails.git', :tag => '0.11'
gem 'showdown-rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'pry', require: 'pry'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors', :git => 'git@github.com:AdamKyle/Rack-Cors.git'

#Assets
gem "font-awesome-rails"

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.15'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano', '~> 1.4'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'simplecov', '0.8.2'
  gem 'json_spec', '1.1.2'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

**Issue:** You have to refresh the form, refill it in, then clicking create works. why?

**Additional Notes:** There is no custom javascript that would be interacting with this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbolinks (as I understand it) uses javascript to grab the body of each page and then populate the page without reloading, so javascripts that you have added might not get loaded correctly.

You really don't need turbolinks for your app to run, so try removing it by deleting the line in  your app/assets/javsascripts/application.js file and your forms should work just fine.